# Do I get billed for each http polling request when using ApolloServer on Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, graphql, google-cloud-functions, apollo-server

I want to deploy an GraphQL server (ApolloServer) instance to GCP/Firebase Cloud Functions.
When testing my function locally using Firebase Functions Emulator
I noticed that each time I open the GraphiQL interface, my terminal starts logging
function executions - I guess this happens solely because of the polling mechanism in GraphQL.

Does anyone know if this also means I get billed 1 function execution for each polling request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you GraphQL implementation polls Cloud Function, you indeed will get charged for each call to Cloud Functions once they're deployed. There is never a charge for calls to the Cloud Functions emulator.